# Fetch an account's id using its Identity

Tags: account, identity, address

In kusama account recovery, you have to have your lost account's id (address) to initiate the recovery process, but when you lost an account, in most cases it's id is forgotten too. If we can kind of find our lost id using its identity it would be very helpful. Hence, my question is:

Is it possible to fetch an account's id using its identity (i.e., name, twitter, riot, etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite the answer you were looking for, however current the only way to do it -

- get all identities via [identity.identityOf](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/storage#identityofaccountid32-optionpalletidentityregistration) (If using the JS API, this would mean a `.entries()` query to get the full map)
- loop through, matching to what you expect (with the accountId extracted as part of the key)
- present list to the user (there will most probably be multiples here, i.e. name, riot, etc. is not guaranteed to be unique - it is user supplied)

The last point is generally why where is no name -> accountId mapping -

- this information is certainly non-unique and user supplied
- it is not really needed for on-chain logic, hence not stored since it would bloat the state

Alternatively, the best non-RPC solution would be to index this offline. (It may already be available in one of the explorers)